# React Native - react hook form - setValue not re-render Controller component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rendering, react-hook-form

## Re-render problem

I have two components:

- MainForm
- CFNumericInput

The values coming from CFNumericInput are correct, but setValue won't render the old one.
Do I have to use an useEffect?

### MainForm

```js
const { control, watch, setValue, register } = useFormContext();

return (
    <CFNumericInput
      name="number1"
      control={control}
      setValueOnChange={(nextValue: string, oldValue: string) => {
        let nextValidValue = checkNumericType(nextValue, "f6.2");
        if (nextValidValue !== "") setValue("number1", nextValidValue);
        else if (oldValue) setValue("number1", oldValue);
      }}
    />;
)
```

### CFNumericInput

```js
export const CFNumericInput: React.FC<any> = ({
  name,
  control,
  setValueOnChange,
}) => {
  return control ? (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      render={({ field }) => {
        return (
          <NumericInput
            {...field} // onChange, onBlur, value, name, ref
            title={title}
            onChange={(e) => {
              field.onChange(e);
              setValueOnChange && setValueOnChange(e, field.value);
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  ) : (
    <></>
  );
};
```

### Working but heavy solution

This solution it's working, but it's really heavy.

```js
const [number1] = watch(["number1"]);

const [old, setOld] = useState("");
useEffect(() => {
  let nextValidValue = checkNumericType(number1, "f6.2");
  if (nextValidValue !== "") {
    setValue("number1", nextValidValue);
    setOld(nextValidValue);
  } else if (old) setValue("number1", old);
}, [number1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't possible that you call `checkNumericType` on `onSubmit`?
Also you can try on looking to use Yup (take a look at: https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage/#CustomHookwithResolver)

let me know what have you tried

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
For now I'm ok with the heavy solution, too little time to find an alternative.
`checkNumericType` is never used inside `onSubmit`.
Tbh idk yup at all, maybe there is a real time check at every onChange that I can run and I missed it.

Comment: Yeah I thought of `onSubmit` because then it would check only once instead of every keystroke